# Logitech z623 2.1 Left Speaker Not Working

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, realtek-hd-audio

The left speaker is not working despite being connected. I turned the volume to max and min on the dial knob and all I could hear was a static/buzzing-like noise that reflected on the volume knob. They have worked before but I only use them once in a while, as I use AirPods via Bluetooth most of the time.

I've searched for answers here, on Reddit, and on other websites and have not found an answer. I've done the basics such as restarting, unplugging/plugging - also switching into different inputs, looking through all the sound settings I could find and read about, up-to-date pre-installed sound drivers, up-to-date GeForce game drivers (which also included audio), and plugged it into a Dell laptop.

The outcome is still the same, static on the left and sound on right. Does this mean it is a hardware issue and needs to get the left speaker replaced?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If that was the solution, then it probably needs to be re-soldered to make a reliable connection inside the sub-woofer unit.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

(solved) I hope this post can help others and give them ideas on what to do. 3 minutes after making this post, I was about to give up. I looked on the back of the subwoofer, unplugged the left speaker, wiggled the female port, reinsert it, and somehow it just worked again. Not sure if this would work for others but might as well give it a try!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.